# I'm trying to install SMLNJ using iTerm and ZSH but I keep getting "sml: cannot find runtime system /usr/local/smlnj/bin/.run/run.-"

Tags: zsh, smlnj, iterm

I'm trying to install SMLNJ using iTerm and ZSH. I've installed SMLNJ successfully using Brew. I'm using an Macbook Pro with and M2 chip.

I've installed SMLNJ using brew with the following command:
`brew install smlnj --cask`

This seems to have successfully installed the latest version.

I then saw some instructions saying I need to add the following to my `.bash_profile` file

`export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.79/libexec/bin:$PATH`

but I'm using ZSH so I've tried to add this command to my `.zshrc` file.

I'm still getting `zsh: command not found: sml`

I also saw another command:

`sml: cannot find runtime system /usr/local/smlnj/bin/.run/run.-`

which I've added into my `.zshrc` file replacing the previous command, `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.79/libexec/bin:$PATH`.

Doing this I get the following message:

`sml: cannot find runtime system /usr/local/smlnj/bin/.run/run.-`

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: I would put the setting into .zshenv instead of .zshrc, so that you also have it available when you are running a fresh, non-interactive zsh. But for most cases, .zshrc should work too. Start a new shell with `zsh -x`, so that you see what commands are getting executed. Do you observe the modification of your PATH? Maybe there are several assignments to the variable, and a later one destroys your previous value.

Comment: The most recent Homebrew smlnj is 110.99 - not 110.79, which is from 2015 - so you probably need a slightly different path.